# How to add image to Twitter Bootstrap with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am using **twitter** **bootstrap** template in My **laravel** app.

I need add image which include in my **imgs** folder in public folder **home.jpg**. how can I add this image to following bootstrap scripts.

```
<div class="item active">
  <img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>Example headline.</h1>
      <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel By default takes public folder path **public/**

Let's say your home.jpg file is in **public/image/home.jpg**

so in your html it will be `<img src="http://localhost:8000/image/home.jpg">`

Laravel also has specific methode `{{ HTML::image('image/home.jpg') }}` for this.

For mere refer http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/185/generating-an-html-image-element

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I got solutions this is working

```
<img class="first-slide" src="{{asset('/imgs/1.gif')}} " alt="First slide">
```